# Backbone Collection not unique?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a simple setup going for the beginnings of an app in Backbone.js
The code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3935931).
It is pretty straightforward.  A `Coin` model and collection, a `Player` model and collection.  Each Player has a collection of Coins.  I manually add the type of Coins a player should be getting.

At the end of `initialize`, each of the Players `Coins` collection has 32 items in it and `Coins.player_id` is set to 4 in all 4 Players.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that your problem is your `defaults` in `Player`:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        coins: new Coins()
    },
    //...
});
```

That `defaults` will be shallow-copied to new `Player`s so they'll all end up sharing exactly the same `coins: new Coins()`. Similar things happen whenever `defaults` contains any mutable data (i.e. arrays, object literals, ...). So all of these:

```
this.Taylor.get("coins")
this.Sugar.get("coins")
this.Darlene.get("coins")
this.Cody.get("coins")
```

will end up as the exact same object. The [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) has this to say:

> **defaults** `model.defaults or model.defaults()`
>
> The **defaults** hash (or function) can be used to specify the default attributes for your model. When creating an instance of the model, any unspecified attributes will be set to their default value.
>   [...]
>   *Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances.*

Note that little caveat at the end. If you use a function for `defaults`:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            id: 0,
            name: '',
            coins: new Coins()
        };
    },
    //...
});
```

then you should get distinct `'coins'` for each `Player`. Alternatively, you could manually set `'coins'` in your `initialize`:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        this.set('coins', new Coins);
        // Or only set it if it isn't there if that makes sense...
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had no idea about the objects being done by reference in Defaults....excuse me while I go modify some past projects.....