# Objects and Arrays of one instance are getting referenced by new instance of Backbone model

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, backbone.js, model

I am using backbone model and quite surprised to see that my JSON objects and arrays which are set inside a particular instance of my Backbone model are getting accessible by other instances too.

```
 var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { 
    exp: [],
    name: '',
    json: { }
  },
  
  getExp: function() {
    return this.get('exp');
  },
  
  getJSON: function() {
    return this.get('json');
  }
});

var m1 = new myModel();
var experiences = m1.getExp();
experiences.push('arrayitem1');
experiences.push('arrayitem2'); //Setting values for array of m1

m1.set('name', 'my name');

var json = m1.getJSON();
json.key = 'somevalue';

var m2 = new myModel();
console.log(m1.attributes);
console.log(m2.attributes);
```

Output:

```
{"exp": ["arrayitem1", "arrayitem2"], "json": {"key": "somevalue"}, "name": "my name"}
{"exp": ["arrayitem1", "arrayitem2"], "json": {"key": "somevalue"}, "name": ""}
```

Key-value pairs of m2

- Name property inside m2 is default. (As expected)
- exp : Same as in m1 (Not expected)
- json: Same as in m1 (Not expected)

## [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ihocun/1/edit)

I am unable to reason for this behavior.

**Update**

I want to know how should I solve it. I have added an answer (Kinda hacky) as it is working for me but I do not know if it is right or not. Would love to know the reason for this behaviour too. What wrong am I doing or Is this some kind of bug in Backbone.

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031354/reset-backbone-collections-in-backbone-model/16031419#16031419

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr This is working http://jsbin.com/ihocun/4/edit

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/13022105/479863 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/14489672/479863 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/13042787/479863 or ...

Comment: @nikoshr: Do you know of a canonical "`defaults` is shallow copied" question that we can send all the duplicates to? I've answered several questions that come down to that issue but they're not really duplicates.

Comment: @muistooshort I thought I remembered a few good candidates but I can't find one.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes you are right. Each question comes with own little bit specifications that's why their titles and question body is different and hence little difficult to find a generic question. May be you can post one and answer yourself. That will help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hack I have used to solve this problem. Reset all the objects and arrays used as attributes in Backbone model in `initialize` method.

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { 
    exp: [],
    name: '',
    json: { }
  },

  getExp: function() {
    return this.get('exp');
  },

  getJSON: function() {
    return this.get('json');
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.set('exp', []);
    this.set('json', {});
  }
});

var m1 = new myModel();
var experiences = m1.getExp();
experiences.push('arrayitem1');
experiences.push('arrayitem2');

m1.set('name', 'my name');
var json = m1.getJSON();
json.key = 'somevalue';

var m2 = new myModel();
console.log(m1.attributes);
console.log(m2.attributes);
```

## [Working Demo at JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ihocun/2/edit)